# Spock test if method was called by constructor

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, spock

I have a Firebase admin helper class that I am testing with Spock. The constructor of this class will call another method in the class to initialize certain fields if it has to, as shown below:

```java
public class FirebaseUtility {
    private static FirebaseDatabase db = null;

    public FirebaseUtility() throws IOException {
        if (db == null) {
            initializeFirebase();
        }
    }

    public void initializeFirebase() throws IOException {
        InputStream serviceAccount = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("serviceAccount.json");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("<my_database_url>").build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Basically, there is no point in doing all the initialization code if the FirebaseDatabase is already set.

I have tried doing this, but it does not seem to work:

```java
class FirebaseUtilitySpec extends Specification {

    def "instantiating FirebaseUtility should run initialization code"() {
        given:
            def f
        when:
            f = new FirebaseUtility()
        then:
            1 * f.initializeFirebase()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot check interactions on original objects, you need to use a mock or spy. Furthermore, those types of objects cannot intercept interactions on static methods or constructors. For that you would have to add Mockito or even PowerMock to the mix. But basically, static methods are just ugly anyway and initialising a static member in a constructor call is not necessary. Just use a lazy getter for the database object and intercept its behaviour.

I have simplified your example a bit, removing the external dependency and just emulating Firebase so as to make it easier to answer with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class FirebaseDatabase {
  private static FirebaseDatabase instance;

  public static FirebaseDatabase getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
      instance = new FirebaseDatabase();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class FirebaseUtility {
  private static FirebaseDatabase db = null;

  public FirebaseDatabase getDb() {
    if (db == null)
      initializeFirebase();
    return db;
  }

  protected void initializeFirebase() {
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

class FirebaseUtilitySpec extends Specification {
  def "instantiating FirebaseUtility runs initialization code exactly once"() {
    given:
    FirebaseUtility f = Spy()

    when:
    f.getDb()
    then:
    1 * f.initializeFirebase()

    when:
    f.getDb()
    then:
    0 * f.initializeFirebase()
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example does make a lot of sense and looks best for testing, but is it good design to have "db" set lazily when the class isn't of much use without it being set? It just seems more appropriate to be in a constructor since every other action taken relies on it having a valid value.

Comment: Why set it before it is used the very first time? A constructor is meant to construct an object, not to have side-effects. Plus, in your example it would even have to declare a checked exception completely unrelated to object construction. It is also ugly that without the getter you have to make your property public. BTW, a static property can also be initialised in a static block right after class-loading. But that is even harder to test.

Comment: I agree that the exception in a constructor is a bit nasty. The reason why I had it set in the constructor was because every other method in the class was going to need it before doing any CRUD operations. Also that property shouldn't need to be used outside the class either, so I wouldn't necessarily need a getter or make it public. I still do like your design though, so I may just live with the fact of calling initalize() separately after instantiating FIrebaseUtility

Comment: Then is there anything else keeping you from accepting the answer? BTW, I do think that the `FirebaseDatabase` instance should be injectable so as to enable you to better test your whole application. Then you could easily inject a mock and verify its usage. Maybe you even want to provide an option to inject `serviceAccount` or the parsed DB credentials. As of now testability of your class is suboptimal and hard-wired dependencies make for tight component coupling instead of loos coupling. Maintainability and modularisation are also important.